# Referring to object properties during declaration?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

So I have this object, and I am wondering how I refer to other properties while declaring:

```
var Chatter = function(io){
    this.base_url = "http://chat.chatter.com:1337";
    this.debug_on = true;
    this.socket = io.connect(this.base_url);
    this.socket.on('acknowledge', this.acknowledge);
}
Chatter.prototype.debug = function(msg){
    if(this.debug_on){
        var m = {timestamp:Date.create().format('{yyyy}-{MM}-{dd} {24hr}:{mm}:{ss}{tt}'), message:msg};
        console.debug('#[ chatter DEBUG ]# - {timestamp} - {message}'.assign(m));
    }
}
Chatter.prototype.acknowledge = function(data){
    this.debug('Acknowledgement received!'); //This throws an error, claims #debug is not there
    this.uuid = data.uuid;
};
```

Calling `this.debug()` fails but on line 5, calling `this.acknowledge` works. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Learn more about how `this` works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Comment: On line 5 you aren't actually calling `this.acknowledge`, you are passing it as a callback to be called later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with `Chatter.prototype.acknowledge` (see http://jsfiddle.net/aEdvh/ )

It's with the way you're calling it.

```
this.socket.on('acknowledge', this.acknowledge);
```

Calls `acknowledge` with the value of `this` in the socket callback (see [this guide](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.general)).

You need to bind the value of `this`  to the context. Try using [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
this.socket.on('acknowledge', this.acknowledge.bind(this));
```

If you need to support older browsers like IE8, or you don't like bind, you can do so manually as such

```
   var that = this;
   this.socket.on('acknowledge', function(data){
       that.acknowledge(data);
   });
```